# How do I remove all the spaces between the card in gridview.builder

Tags: flutter, dart

I need help regarding my `gridview.builder`, my gridview [become like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ysu2S.png), this happened because I want to filter to show only item that has the same id. I already try to put `padding: EdgetInsets.zero`and `SizedBox.shrink` but it still does not work. How can I remove the blank card and only show the visible card? if I remove `return Card()`

```
Stack(
        children: [
          StreamBuilder(
              stream: FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('products').snapshots(),
              builder: (context, AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot> snapshot){
                if(snapshot.hasError){
                  return Text("Error: ${snapshot.error}");
                }
                if(snapshot.hasData){
                  return Column(
                    children: [
                      Flexible(
                          child: GridView.builder(
                              padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
                              itemCount: snapshot.data!.docs.length,
                              gridDelegate: const SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
                                crossAxisCount: 2,
                                mainAxisSpacing: 15,
                                crossAxisSpacing: 15,
                                childAspectRatio: 2/3,
                              ),
                              itemBuilder: (context, index){
                                final DocumentSnapshot documentSnapshot =
                                snapshot.data!.docs[index];
                                DateTime dt = (documentSnapshot['endDateTime'] as Timestamp).toDate();
                                if(documentSnapshot['userid'] == widget.sellerId){
                                  print(documentSnapshot['userid']);
                                  return  buildImageCard(
                                      documentSnapshot['imageURL'][0], documentSnapshot['nameP'],
                                      documentSnapshot['startPrice'], dt, documentSnapshot['id'],
                                      documentSnapshot['categoryP']);
                                }
                                return Card();
                              }
    
                          )
                      ),
                    ],
                  );
                }
                return const Center(
                  child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
                );
              }
    
    
          ),
        ],
      );
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution would be to filter the list of docs above the widget, and use the filtered list for itemCount and the builder.

The cause of the issue is that each widget takes the aspect ratio that your specified (2/3) + the spacing regardless of the size of the child widget.

So it should be a little something like this

```
if(snapshot.hasData){
final listToUse = snapshot.data?.docs.where((documentSnapshot) => documentSnapshot['userid'] == widget.sellerId).toList() ?? [];
return Column(...
```

Comment: I tried the code but instead, it shows less of the item that possessed the same id than before and it still has the space issue